# WPF DataGrid scrollbar appearance

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class, derived from `DataGrid` that stretches the last column, if there is free space right of it:

```
public double? ViewPortWidth 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return FindChild<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>(this, "PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter")?.ActualWidth;
    } 
}

private void StretchLastColumnToTheBorder()
{
    if (IsLoaded && ViewPortWidth.HasValue)
    {
        var widthSum = 0d;
        for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == Columns.Count - 1 && ViewPortWidth > widthSum + Columns[i].ActualWidth)
            {
                var newWidth = Math.Floor(ViewPortWidth.Value - widthSum);
                Columns[i].Width = new DataGridLength(newWidth, DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel);
                return;
            }
            widthSum += Columns[i].ActualWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

`StretchLastColumnToTheBorder()` gets called once `LayoutUpdated` is fired. Everything works fine, unless  the table has enough rows for the vertical scrollbar to appear. Apparently, it appears not immediately after `DataGrid` is loaded, causing wrong width calculation. How can I check, whether vertical scrollbar has been initialized?

**EDIT:**
`Width="Auto"` sizes the column to fit its longest cell. `Width="*"` sets only initial width of the column to stretch to the end. However, if you shrink any of your columns, blank space will appear behind last one.

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent the wheel ? Whats wrong with Width="Auto" and Width="*" for the last column ?

Comment: I edited my post to make clear, what is wrong with them.

Comment: *How can I check, whether vertical scrollbar has been initialized?* Try to find it in the visual tree?

Comment: @mm8 sure, I can find it in the visual tree. But how to check, whether it should be shown at all?

Comment: If it's in the visual tree it's visible (subject to the value of the `Visibility` property of course). If it's not there, there is no scroll bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscription to `LayoutUpdated` in `Loaded` handler solves the problem. In this case `IsLoaded` check is also redundant. So, having

```
public FancyDataGrid() : base()
{
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LayoutUpdated += OnLayoutUpdated;
}
```

instead of

```
public FancyDataGrid() : base()
{
    LayoutUpdated += OnLayoutUpdated;
}
```

allows to access viewport when it's calculated with regard to vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the `ScrollViewer` for the `DataGrid` you can check the `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` property.